# Upgrading from SATA HDD TO SDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, hibernate

I've just bought a new 500 gb SATA SSD, I'm planning to replace my laptop's 2TB HDD with it and connect the hdd to my  laptop using a caddy in place of the dvd...
my questions are:

1. Should i keep the swap,boot and root partitions on it and move the home partion to the hdd,is it even possible,I don't want to overuse it in read/write , my needs will mostly be fast booting(obviously),fast launching of the apps, and may be some games.
   and I'm also planning to try more than one distro,may be two besides windows
2. how much space should I make the swap partition in order to hibernate, I've 12 gb RAM installed, or is better to use a swap file instead.
   thanks

Comment: Do not plan on hibernation and keep swap at either default swap file of 2GB or a swap partition of 4GB. With SSD you can boot just as fast or faster and with fewer issues than recover from hibernation. If USB drive best not to be any essential partitions like /home. Make sure USB caddy works with HDD. Mine worked great with SSD, but only had USB power and would not power up HDD. Put some data files & test installs on HDD.

Comment: @ oldfred  OP wants to take his DVD-drive out of the laptop and replace it with a caddy with his HDD. The HDD will use the SATA-port from the DVD-drive.  Good reply my friend.

Comment: While DVDs boot, we have seen some systems that will not boot from a drive in the place of the DVD caddy. Boot files all then have to be on main drive, but data can then be on drive in caddy.

Comment: thanks @oldfred I'm doing just like Joepie Es said, replacing my dvd with the caddy containg HDD, I decided I'm not gonna put the home partition on HDD I was afraid it may use much read/write of ssd, after some searching turned out it's not a big concern with modern ssd anymore,they may even outlive my own computer

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. 
Like `oldfred` commented there is not really a need for `hybernation`, as your SSD will boot very fast.
What you can do is seperate your `pictures, documents, music, downloads and videos` in your `Windows installation` to your HDD. Then a 200GB partition would be sufficient.
If you plan on using more than 1 Linux-distribution, seperating the same (p,d,m,d & v) from the Linux-OSes would make sense. If you plan on gaming, depending on the size of the games, keep your `/home-partition` on the SSD. But I advice not to use 1 `/home-partition` for both (or more) Linux-distros (especially if they both have the same Desktop Environment) as this could cause conflicts. e.g. If you 2 distros using `KDE Plasma` (`Kubuntu` and `KDE Neon`) `Neon` uses newer software and `Kubuntu` older (more stable). 
Think well ahead and partition the disk accordingly. This will save a lot of work and risk (repartitioning).
Remember that Linux-distros can read and write to `NTFS partitions`. `Windows` cannot read `EXT4/BTRFS-partitions` and third-party software to make Windows do this is unreliable and likely to destroy those partitions.
Hope this clarifies things a little bit for you.

Comment: thanks @Joepie Es I decided I'm gonna partition the ssd into 200 gb partition for my main distro and two 150 gb partitions one partition for windows and 150 to other distros or may be use it later to increase my main distro, I'm new to linux so I wanna try more than one distro , as for the swap partition I'm gonna make it 15 gb I'm used to hibernating and leaving programs open on windows so I'm gonna try it this time with linux, if i find my self not using I will reinstall it again with only 4 gb as you mintioned

Comment: Advice is to install Windows first, then the Linux-distro.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, installed windows first, and I ended up with only 4 gb for the swap partition with no need for hibernation,thanks @Joepie Es